# is it possible to abort <f:ajax> with "return false"?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf, jsf-2

If you do this:

```
<h:commandButton action="..." onclick="return false" />
```

The action will not occur.

The same does not work for `<f:ajax>`, meaning this doesn't work:

```
<f:ajax event="click" onevent="return false" listener="#{mrBean.doSomething()}" >
    <h:commandLink value="A Link"  \>
</f:ajax>
```

Or more correctly, the ajax action runs and I get this error in the javascript console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token return
myfaces._impl.core._Runtime.singletonExtendClass.chainjsf.js.jsf:7491
chainjsf.js.jsf:7696
(anonymous function)file.jsf
onclick
```

Is there a way abort the `<f:ajax>` action through a javascript in a similar fashion to the `h:commandbutton` example?

Comment: Maybe define global function: `function getfalse(e) {return false;}`, 
`<f:ajax ... onevent="getfalse" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this:

```
<f:ajax event="click" onevent="doTheRefreshingPart()" listener="#{mrBean.doSomething()}" >
    <h:commandLink value="A Link" onclick="return doTheConfirmationPart" \>
</f:ajax>
```

I moved the part that is confirmation dependent to the actual commandlink and left the part that takes part of refreshing the page in the `<f:ajax>` part